# Multiply numbers which are divisible by 3 and less than 10 with a while loop in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In C++, I should write a program where the app detects which numbers are divisible by 3 from 1 till 10 and then multiply all of them and print the result. That means that I should multiply 3,6,9 and print only the result, which is 162, but I should do it by using a "While" loop, not just multiplying the 3 numbers with each other. How should I write the code of this? I attached my attempt to code the problem below. Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int x, r;
int l;
x = 1;
r = 0;

while (x < 10 && x%3==0) {
    r = (3 * x) + 3;
    cout << r;
}

cin >> l;
}
```

Comment: Provide an attempt so we can help you. But here is a hint: `*=`

Comment: Sorry for sounding rude but how is that an approach? Can you explain what you think you are doing there (be it with code comments or in your question)

Comment: `cin >> l;` what's the role of `l` in the loop?

Comment: @Rafiwui Sure. First of all, I just posted my first question on the platform (so the question could sound a bit childish), also I know that the code is wrong, but it has been only 2 sessions for the lesson and we didn't learn much yet. The teacher just introduced the while loop and we wrote few code examples and he gave this (unsolvable for the whole class) problem to solve and we tried to solve it with no avail, so I came here to get tips on how to solve it.
We should multiply numbers less than 3 and divisible by 3, which is 3,6 and 9, so the console shows 162

Comment: Hint: The modulo check should not be part of the condition of the while loop like you have it, since as soon as a number is found that is not divisible by 3, the entire loop will end. Move that check to be inside the loop.

Comment: @user0042 just a dumb way for the console to not close after the program finishes

Comment: @KourkenK. ok so i gave you a few hints because like said before this is no solution but a helping site ;) feel free to ask questions about things you don't understand

Comment: @Rafiwui Sure, I'm looking into it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly your checking the condition `x%3 == 0` brings you out of your while - loop right in the first iteration where `x` is `1`. You need to check the condition inside the loop.

Since you wish to store your answer in variable `r` you must initialize it to 1 since the product of anything with 0 would give you 0.

Another important thing is you need to **increment** the value of x at each iteration i.e. to check if **each** number in the range of 1 to 10 is divisible by 3 or not .

```
int main()
{
        int x, r;
        int l;
        x = 1;
        r = 1;

   while (x < 10) 
   {
         if(x%3 == 0)
             r = r*x ;
       x = x + 1; //incrementing the value of x
   }
   cout<<r;
}
```

Lastly I have no idea why you have written the last `cin>>l` statement . Omit it if not required.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Aditi. It worked. Now I have to find how all of this works :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here are a few hints that hopefully help you solving this:

1. Your approach with two variables (x and r) outside the loop is a good starting point for this.
2. Like I wrote in the comments you should use `*=` instead of your formula (I still don't understand how it is related to the problem)
3. Don't check if `x` is dividable by 3 inside the while-check because it would lead to an too early breaking of the loop
4. You can delete your `l` variable because it has no affect at the moment ;)
5. Your output should also happen outside the loop, else it is done everytime the loop runs (in your case this would be 10 times)

I hope I can help ;)

**EDIT:** Forget about No.4. I didn't saw your comment about the non-closing console.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me come closer to what I wanted. I actually didn't need to keep that last l variable so I removed it. (I would upvote, but I don't have enough points for that! :)

Comment: @KourkenK. no worries. Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
  int result = 1; // "result" is better than "r"

  for (int x=1; x < 10; ++x)
  {
    if (x%3 == 0)
      result = result * x;
  }

  cout << result;
}
```

or the loop in short with some additional knowledge:

```
 for (int x=3; x < 10; x += 3) // i know that 3 is dividable
   result *= x;
```

or, as it is c++, and for learning purposes, you could do:

```
vector<int> values; // a container holding integers that will get the multiples of 3

for (int x=1; x < 10; ++x) // as usual
  if ( ! x%3 ) // same as x%3 == 0
    values.push_back(x); // put the newly found number in the container

// now use a function that multiplies all numbers of the container (1 is start value)
result = std::accumulate(values.begin(), values.end(), 1, multiplies<int>());

// so much fun, also get the sum (0 is the start value, no function needed as add is standard)
int sum = std::accumulate(values.begin(), values.end(), 0);
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but we still didn't learn the for loop, so that's why I requested a while loop tips. Anyways, it'll be a good reference to look at when we go over the for loop. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's important to remember the difference between = and ==.  = sets something to a value while == compares something to a value.  You're on the right track with incrementing x and using x as a condition to check your range of numbers. When writing code I usually try and write a "pseudocode" in English to organize my steps and get my logic down. It's also wise to consider using variables that tell you what they are as opposed to just  random letters.  Imagine if you were coding a game and you just had letters as variables; it would be impossible to remember what is what.  When you are first learning to code this really helps a lot. So with that in mind:

```
/*

 - While x is less than 10
 - check value to see if it's mod 3 
 - if it's mod 3 add it to a sum
 - if not's mod 3 bump a counter
 - After my condition is met 
 - print to screen  pause screen

*/
```

Now if we flesh out that pseudocode a little more we'll get a skeletal structure.

```
int main()
{
int x=1//value we'll use as a counter
int sum=0//value we'll use as a sum to print out at the end

while(x<10)//condition we'll check against
{
  if (x mod 3 is zero)
   {
     sum=x*1;
     increment x
   }
  else
   {
     increment x
   }
}
//screen output the sum the sum
//system pause or cin.get() use whatever your teacher gave you.
```

I've given you a lot to work with here you should be able to figure out what you need from this. Computer Science and programming is hard and will require a lot of work.  It's important to develop good coding habits and form now as it will help you in the future. Coding is a skill like welding; the more you do it the better you'll get. I often refer to it as the "Blue Collar Science" because it's really a *skillset* and not just raw knowledge.  It's not like studying history or Biology (minus Biology labs) because those require you to learn things and loosely apply them whereas programming requires you to actually build something.  It's like welding or plumbing in my opinion.

Additionally when you come to sites like these try and read up how things should be posted and try and seek the "logic" behind the answer and come up with it on your own as opposed to asking for the answer. People will be more inclined to help you if they think you're working for something instead of asking for a handout (not saying you are, just some advice).  Additionally take the attitude these guys give you with a grain of salt, Computer Scientists aren't known to be the worlds most personable people. =) Good luck.

Comment: I think I should get few lessons from your answer. First, I should definitely use words instead of letters to clarify everything. I really liked the comment with the steps to make things more clear, at the moment we're working on flowcharts first (on paper), then coding, but I liked the comment approach too.

I have to say that some things we didn't learn yet, but we're working on the while loop at the moment.

I actually know HTML and CSS for over a year, so I'm into web development and I understand that programming is hard, but I love coding and that's why I chose it :)

Comment: Also, this was my first question here, so I'll get to know the rules better over time and post more. It wasn't actually handout, but we were struggling with this problem for 3 days now, so that's why I asked here. I think the best thing to do here is to ask for tips (not for partial or whole solutions).

I hope that I'll stay with the same attitude that I have atm even after I become a CS programmer and Developer. :D

Comment: Your approach won't work. You are using `sum = x * 1` and this will result at the end with the highest number lower 10 that is divisible by 3. Your sum should start with 1 and the it should be `sum = sum * x` or `sum *= x`